# Custom Control with Image as Property

Tags: c#, image, properties, custom-controls

I am working on a `CustomControl` which should have a `Property` which is an `Image`.

```
public Image BackgroundPicture{ set; get };
```

But when the `Image` is set to `(none)` then the Visual Studio Designer throws an Error :

> Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.Drawing.Image'.

Is there any efficient way to prevent this problem??